# Looking to build a Facebook-style footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, facebook

I am a freelance developer looking to build a new social networking site, and I really enjoy Facebook's footer and how it looks / works.

I'm not really sure how I would get started on making something similar? jQuery? CSS?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

[Soh Tanaka](http://www.sohtanaka.com/) features a two-part tutorial on his website about this same exact topic. A majority of his tutorials are very easy to follow and straight to the point.

You can find the start of the tutorial [here](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/facebook-style-footer-admin-panel-part-1/), (It's a two-parter) and a working-demo of the same tutorial is available here:

Hope this helped you out - or at least gave you some ideas to play with.

[Building a Facebook Style Footer Admin Panel](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/examples/footer-panel/)